# SQL subquery aggregates wrong

Tags: mysql

I have a scoreboard that shows current ranking based on most average points gained.

me and 6 friends play several rounds per evening.

We keep track of:
Playername (playerid)
Point (sum of all points accumulated over the rounds)
rounds (how many rounds are played)
Average points (points / rounds)

This works but I want to add a calculation if players rise or fall in the scoreboard and by how many average points.

this is my code:

```
SELECT   t1.playerid as player
                ,SUM(t1.points) AS points
                ,count(t1.playerid) AS rounds
                ,avg(t1.points) as average_points

/* get tournament ID of last round */
                ,(select distinct(tournamentid) from pokermax_scores order by tournamentid desc limit 1,1) as 1_round_ago

/* calculate average points earned one round ago */                
                ,(select avg(points) from pokermax_scores  where tournamentid <= 1_round_ago group by t1.playerid) as avg_last
                ,(avg(t1.points)-(select avg(points) from pokermax_scores  where tournamentid <= 1_round_ago group by t1.playerid)) as gain_loss
FROM pokermax_scores as t1
GROUP BY player
ORDER BY average_points DESC
```

1_round_ago is the tournamentid for the round before last.

however its not calculating the averages of the last round correctly, but instead takes the average OF the average of last round.

result:

[image]

as you can see here the avg_last is wrong. Here excel example of where the number is coming from:

[image]

Any clue how to correct the code? tried OVER() but its not supported by MariaDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a correlated subquery to get the average for the player in the row. Change:

```
(select avg(points) 
from pokermax_scores  
where tournamentid <= 1_round_ago 
group by t1.playerid)
```

to:

```
(select avg(points) 
from pokermax_scores t2 
where tournamentid <= 1_round_ago 
and t2.playerid = t1.playerid)
```